# How to Define a Piecewise Function in Python with Multiple Variables

Tags: python, for-loop, sympy, bessel-functions

I am trying to develop a plot for my helioseismology class and the question had provided a piecewise function describing the dynamics of the "fluids" in a star as if it is one thing its this and if its another its that. I am receiving over and over again this `'Mul' object cannot be interpreted as an integer` but I am working with numbers in the reals not just the integer set. I do not know how to get around this and need guidance. The code is as follows.

```
import sympy as sy
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.units import Unit
import numpy as np
import sys
import math
import scipy as sp
from scipy import special

phi = Symbol('phi', Variable = True)
x = Symbol('x', Variable = True, Real = True)
t = Symbol('t', Variable = True, Real = True)
xi = Symbol('xi', Function = True)
Solar_Radius = Symbol('R', Constant = True, unit = "meters")
Sound_Speed = Symbol('c', Constant = True, unit = "meters per second", Real = True)
gamma = Symbol('gamma', Constant = True)
gravity = Symbol('g', Constant = True, unit = "meters per second per second")

Solar_Radius = 6.963 * 10 ** 6
gamma = 5/3
g = 274.8265625336
gas_constant = 8201.25
c = 8.1 * 10 ** 3

for t in range(0,x/c):
    xi[x,t] = 0
for t in range(x/c,00):
    xi[x,t] = (1/2)*sy.exp(gamma*g*x/(2*c**2))*mpmath.besselj(0, (gamma*g/(2*c)*sy.sqrt(t**2 - ((x/c)**2))),derivative = 0)
```

Full Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-3506376f1686> in <module>()
----> 1 for t in range(0,x/c):
      2     xi[x,t] = 0
      3 for t in range(x/c,00):
      4     xi[x,t] = (1/2)*sy.exp(gamma*g*x/(2*c**2))*mpmath.besselj(0, (gamma*g/(2*c)*sy.sqrt(t**2 - ((x/c)**2))),derivative = 0)

TypeError: 'Mul' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

Comment: Clean up your imports. Then break up that complicated statement into multiple steps to see which line the error will come from until you know what operation or object is at fault.

Comment: each of the three major "blurbs" are separated, I am sorry if that was misleading. the problem starts in the for loop and i do not know why. I will not know if the bessel function is clear or not until I get this out of the way first

Comment: It seems that (x/c) cannot be interpreted as an integer. Have you looked at what kind of object that is? Does it make sense to have an integer value? If so, look at the object type with type(x/c), find what library that defines that type, and google "library type integer representation".

Comment: it says `sympy.core.mul.Mul` for `type(x/c)`

Comment: Don't use `*` for imports, it makes things more confusing than they need to be.

Comment: for the x/c it would make sense if it were an integer, but that is because it should be an element of the real numbers as is. looking at the second diagram [on here] (http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/manipulation.html) is not telling me very much however.

Comment: @IanAuld i took your comment into account, thanks for the advice. i believe you wanted me to write `import sympy` as whatever

Comment: Why should it matter if it were an integer, imaginary, non-set theory number, anything really. Maybe a bit far on that last one, but what is it that is stopping python???

Comment: `range` is a python builtin that requires integer input afaik. It does not make sense to pass a sympy object. 

Also check your syntax:

`sympy.Symbol("x", Real=True).is_real` --> None

`sympy.Symbol("x", real=True).is_real` --> True

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are quite a few issues here:

- None of the keyword arguments (Constant, Variable, unit, Real) that you are passing to Symbol are things that are recognized by SymPy. The only one that is close is `real`, which should be lowercase (like `Symbol('x', real=True)`). The rest do nothing. If you want units, you should use the SymPy units module in `sympy.physics.units`. There is no need to specify if a symbol is constant or variable.
- You have redefined `Solar_Radius` and `gamma` as numbers. That means that the Symbol definitions for those variables are pointless.
- If you are using Python 2, make sure to include `from __future__ import division` at the top of the file, or else things like `1/2` and `5/3` will be truncated with integer division (this isn't an issue in Python 3).
- `range(0, x/c)` doesn't make sense. `range` creates a list of numbers, like `range(0, 3)` -> `[0, 1, 2]`. But `x/c` is not a number, it's a symbolic expression.
- Additionally, `xi[x, t] = ...` doesn't make sense. `xi` is a Symbol, which doesn't allow indexing and certainly doesn't allow assignment.
- Don't mix numeric (math, mpmath, numpy, scipy) functions with SymPy functions. They won't work with symbolic expressions. You should use only SymPy functions. If you create a symbolic expression and want to convert it to a numeric one (e.g., for plotting), use `lambdify`.

What you want here is `Piecewise`. The syntax is `Piecewise((expr, cond), (expr, cond), ..., (expr, True))`, where `expr` is an expression that is used when `cond` is true (`(expr, True)` is the "otherwise" condition).

For your example, I believe you want

```
expr = Piecewise((0, t < x/c), (sy.exp(gamma*g*x/(2*c**2))*sy.besselj(0, (gamma*g/(2*c)*sy.sqrt(t**2 - (x/c)**2)))/2, t >= x/c))
```

If you want to turn this into a numeric function in `x` and `t`, use

```
xi = lambdify((x, t), expr)
```